How to unblock windows firewall for a specific ip address?
I'm using wsl2 ubuntu22.04 on a windows10 system. There's a proxy app running on my windows. I want to use this proxy from my wsl2 command line. The wsl2 ip is 172.26.198.212 .
The firewall log shows my window10 keeps dropping packets from this address on port 7890:
2024-11-05 14:04:38 DROP TCP 172.26.198.212 172.26.192.1 50968 7890 60 S 3368890042 0 64240 - - - RECEIVE
And when I turned off the firewall for public network, everything worked fine:

So I think I need to add the inbound rule for 172.26.198.212:

But this didn't work. Where's the problem?

WSL2 often appears as a public network to Windows, even if you’re on a private network. Make sure the rule is set to apply to Public as well as Private.

And have you tried allowing all IPs in the private network range to test whether the rule scope is the issue?

Also, sorry to spam, but  have you confirmed that the proxy app is set to bind to 0.0.0.0 or 127.0.0.1. If it’s only listening on the Windows loopback address (127.0.0.1), WSL2 might not be able to access it directly. Just an idea.


The profile is set to All, which includes both private and public.
I tried allowing all ip address in 172.26.192.0/20.
As I mentioned, if I turn the firewall of public network off, I can proxy smoothly in wsl2, so it should be ok for the third comment?

